# How to divide N participants among M teams so that minimum pairs are formed?

Tags: algorithm

If I have two numbers, i.e. `N` and `M`, and I have to find out how to divide `N` people among `M` teams such that minimum number of pairs are formed in each team, then how should I go about it? (Also, each team should have atleast one member)

For example, if I have `N = 6` and `M = 3`,
then, each team should have 2 people. Therefore, total 3 teams, means 3 pairs are formed.

I know that I have to distribute such that the distribute should be as even as possible. But I am not able to come up with a proper algorithm for the same. Thanks!

Comment: What will happen in the case of `n = 7` and `m = 3`? Will one team have an extra member or will that lonely participant be left out?

Comment: One team will have an extra member, yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. First, put `n/m` people in each team.

You have `n%m` (n modolus m) players still remaining, split them randomly to the teams, but each team can get AT MOST one of these "extra" players.

---

An intuition why this is true is simple on the case of m=2:

You need to split n players into `x` and `n-x`, and you want to minimize the number of pairs:

```
x(x-1)/2 + (n-x)(n-x-1)/2 = 
= (x^2-x + n^2 -2nx + x^2 -n +x)/2
```

Use derivitives to find minima:

```
d(x^2-x + n^2 -2nx + x^2 -n -x)/2/dx = 2x -1 -2n +2x +1 = 4x-2n
```

Look when the above equals 0:

```
4x-2n = 0 -> x=n/2
```

The result will be similar (as closest as possible to `n/m`) for any `m>0`, just harder to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer, but with an outline for a more straightforward proof. Suppose you have two teams that differ in their number of players by more than 1, i.e. one team with k players and one team with k+j players where k >=1 and j >=2. Show that if you move one player from the team with k+j players to the team with k players, then you will get a strictly smaller number of pairs, using binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

1. Number of completed teams = `n / m`.
2. Number of players that don't have any team: `n % m`.

Now you have two options:

1. Create a new team composed of the remaining players.
2. Give one more player to each team until you don't have alone players.

I understand you choose the option 2.

I'll show you a code in Java that probably could help you.

(I know that your question don't have a java tag, but is a high programming language quite easy to understand)

```
int people = n;
int numberOfTeams = m;
int peopleAlone = n;

int initialPeopleForTeam = n/m;

 //This is an array of teams where each element of array is a team,
// and his value the number of people that have the team.
        int teams[] = new int [numberOfTeams];


//each team starts with n/m players. 
     for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        teams[i] = initialPeopleForTeam;
        peopleAlone = peopleAlone - initialPeopleForTeam;
    }

 //While the number of people alone is not 0, I'll give one more  person  to each team.
      int index = 0;
      while (peopleAlone > 0){
      teams[index] = teams[index] + 1;
      index++;
      peopleAlone--;
     }
```